# Property "objects" not found on object of type

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue, detailview

I have a problem with the bookstableview.m segue. if you look bellow there where it says PFObject *object = [self.objects objectatindex.indexPath.row] there is an error under "objects" saying "Property objects not found  on object of type 'BooksTableViewController'."

here is the rest of the code: Bookstableview.m

```
#import "BooksTableViewController.h"
#import "BookDetailViewController.m"

@interface BooksTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation BooksTableViewController

@synthesize bookstableview;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(RetrieveDatafromParse)];
}

-(void) RetrieveDatafromParse {
    PFQuery * getbooks = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"BooksTableView"];

    [getbooks findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            Booksarray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: objects];
        }
        [bookstableview reloadData];
        NSLog(@"%@",objects);
    }];    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:     (NSInteger)section
{    
    return Booksarray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [bookstableview    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell ==nil) {
        cell = [[ UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    PFObject * tempObject = [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Books"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= [tempObject objectForKey:@"Code"];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"booksseg" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject * object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"BooksTableView"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setFile:file];
    }
}
@end
```

bookstableview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface BooksTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate >
{
    NSArray * Booksarray;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *bookstableview;

@end
```

Booksdetailview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "BooksTableViewController.h"
@interface BookDetailViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *BookImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bookTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *bookDesc;
@property (weak,nonatomic) PFObject *file;
@end
```

Comment: The error is clear. Your class does not have such a property.

Comment: How do i fix it, I'm pretty new to this stuff?

Comment: Did you mean to use `BooksArray` rather than `self.objects`?

Comment: Oh thanks man! That fixed the error but my set won't initialise now. I connected it manually to "detail view" from tableview and gave it identifier.When i click the cell it won't switch.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `self.objects` with `Booksarray`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject * object = [Booksarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"BooksTableView"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setFile:file];
    }
}
```

Also: normally, only class names are capitalized, while variables and methods begin with a lower-case letter, so `_booksArray` would be a more appropriate name for the variable. Helps avoid confusion and prevents overlap between class/variable names.

Comment: Wasn't that CRD's comment 8 minutes ago?

Comment: Ah, whoops, I guess so

Comment: Yep, thanks anyway it go rid of the error, but my seg won't initialise on click :S

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"booksseg" sender:self];` to see if it's actually being hit. It doesn't look like you're setting an accessory view on the cell, so `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` may be a more appropriate method to override.

Comment: I just tried the breakpoint and it isn't hitting the identifier.I changed the cell accessory from "disclosure" to "diclosure detail" and it worked only when i pushed the question mark but my detail view was not puling data into my labels or picture.

Comment: Can you post the implementation for your detail view controller?

Comment: This is the only thing i changed  - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.bookTitle.text = [self.file objectForKey:@"Books"];
    self.BookImage.image = [self.file objectForKey:@"BookImage"];
    self.bookDesc.text =[self.file objectForKey:@"BookDetails"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

Comment: This thread is getting a bit off-topic, so I think you're just going to have to do some debugging. Try setting breakpoints at key places in your code and examining the file and view variables to make sure they are what you expect. If you still can't get it after that, you can always post another question.